# Issue with StreamTokenizer in java

Tags: java

I have a string that starts with ASCII character 18 which is read by a stream tokenizer in java. I am initializing stream tokenizer as below:

```
streamTokenizer.wordChars(0,255);
       
streamTokenizer.whitespaceChars(3,3);
```

However in a loop, when i try to get `tokenizer.sval`, it is skipping the first character(ascii 18) and reading rest. It is working fine if the string that starts with ascii 18 is a substring(not a starting string). Any ideas.

```
    Ex: This is the char array of string:
    '\u0012'(Skips this when comes in the beginning)'a''W''4''\u0011''\u0013'
```

Example code:

```
    

public static void main(String args[]){
    Character ESCAPINGCHAR = 18;
    String value = "test";
    value = ESCAPINGCHAR+value;
    try{
        StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(newStringReader(value));
        tokenizer.wordChars(0,255);
        tokenizer.whitespaceChars(3,3);
        for (int counter = 0; tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF; counter++)
        {
        System.out.println(tokenizer.sval)//Missing ESCAPINGCHAR;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
    }}
```

Comment: How about a [mre] that demonstrates the behavior you describe?

Comment: @Josh Bollinger

Comment: try
        {
            for (int counter = 0; tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF; counter++)
            {
                switch (tokenizer.sval)--> This will have the string without the starting char of ASCII 18.

Comment: (1) that is not a MRE.  Follow the link I provided if you're uncertain what we mean by that term.  (2) Provide the MRE by *[editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64102941/edit)*, not by adding comments.

Comment: @JoshBollinger added MRE. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `StreamTokenizer` character attributes (whitespace, word character, *etc*.) are not mutually exclusive.  You successfully mark `0x12` as a word character, but that does not affect the fact that it is a whitespace character by default.  It is both.

The tokenizer starts by consuming whitespace, so it eats the leading `0x12`.  The first non-whitespace it sees is a `'t'`, which is a word character, so the tokenizer enters word mode.  In that mode, it reads characters until it encounters one that is not a word character, so it will indeed accept internal appearances of `0x12`.

It appears that you want only (runs of) byte `0x3` to serve as a delimiters, with all other characters serving as word characters only.  In that case, you'll want to clear the default attributes of substantially all characters via `ordinaryChar()` and / or `ordinaryChars()` before setting the new attributes.  Something like this, for example:

```
        StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(value));
        tokenizer.ordinaryChars(0,255);
        tokenizer.wordChars(0,2);
        tokenizer.whitespaceChars(3,3);
        tokenizer.wordChars(4,255);

        // read tokens ...
```